How to sort a non-meta field in the User Admin Panel?
I'm stuck, and haven't been able to find an answer after much searching.
I need to modify the User Admin Panel showing the list of users and the number of posts. I have custom posts (type = 'articles') I, so the default 'posts' only shows zero.
I thought I might be able to change the standard posts count to include my articles, but couldn't find a way. Instead I've added a new column.
I can populate my new column with the proper count of articles. I also have that number linking to the list of articles by that author.
The only thing I cannot figure out is how to sort the column. I've tried every way I could find or think of. I'm just not that deep into WordPress or SQL.
I'm using the following filters.
// add the new column
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'my_users_articles_column' );
function my_users_articles_column( $columns ) {
  $columns['articles_count'] = 'Count';
  return $columns;
}

// get the value for each row
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'my_users_articles_column_value', 10, 3 );
function my_users_articles_column_value( $value, $column_name, $id ) {
  if ( $column_name == 'articles_count' ) {
    $count = count_user_posts($id, 'articles');
    $link = '<a href="/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=articles&author=' . $id . '">' . $count . '</a>';
    $return = ($count > 0) ? $link : $count;
    return $return;
  }
}

// make the column sortable
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'my_articles_count_column_sortable' );
function my_articles_count_column_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['articles_count'] = 'articles_count';
    return $columns;
}

So, after the basic code above, I have the new column for the count of all articles for each author. And it's clickable to trigger a sort, but it's sorting based on the author's name (the first column) not my article count.
I cannot find a way to get this column to sort. Filters/hooks I've tried include 'pre_get_users', 'pre_user_query', 'request', and others. Not sure which is the right filter. But I don't think I have the right sorting method regardless.
The column isn't a meta field. It's populated from a query. I tried something typical, as below, but this doesn't work.
add_filter('pre_get_users', 'my_pre_get_users');
function my_pre_get_users( $vars ) {
    if ( 'article_count' == $vars['orderby'] ) {
        $vars['meta_key'] = 'article_count';
        $vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
    }
    return $vars;
}

At this point, I could only guess I need to JOIN tables, but that's getting beyond my coding skills. I would continue hacking on this forever at this point.
I've followed answers in several articles such as:

Sort All Posts by Category Name in the Admin Panel?
How to make in WordPress admin panel sortable column for the custom field, that count the number of page impressions?
Sortable Custom Columns in User Panel (users.php)?


Apparently, WordPress tries really hard to limit the things you can sort users by (see WP_User_Query::parse_orderby(), but I think I see a way for a workaround. Trying it out.

The WP_User_Query::parse_orderby() actually supports sorting by the number of posts, but because WP_User_Query::parse_orderby() limits by what users can be sorted, accomplishing a custom sort is a bit of a hack.
Here's the workaround I've created (semi-tested):
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', static function ( $columns ) {
    $columns['articles_count'] = array(
        'articles_count',
        false,
        __( 'Articles' ),
        __( 'Table ordered by number of articles.' ),
    );

    return $columns;
} );

/**
 * Because `parse_orderby()` will discard 'articles_count',
 * set it to `post_count`, and create a custom query var for
 * reference later.
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_users', static function ( $query ) {
    if ( 'articles_count' !== $query->get( 'orderby' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $query->set( 'orderby', 'post_count' );
    $query->set( 'sort_articles_count', true );
} );

/**
 * Check for our custom query var, and change the SQL
 * for sorting users.
 */
add_action( 'pre_user_query', static function ( $query ) {
    if ( ! $query->get( 'sort_articles_count' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $search  = get_posts_by_author_sql( 'post' );
    $replace = get_posts_by_author_sql( 'articles' );

    $query->query_from = str_replace( $search, $replace, $query->query_from );
} );


Whoa! It's working. Now I got to study this and figure out how this works. Very much appreciated. My forehead was pounding the desktop for too long.
